# How do I prevent a recursively defined optparse-applicative Parser from hanging?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, lazy-evaluation, applicative, optparse-applicative

Supposing I have the following recursively defined ADT

```hs
data GraphType = Character | Colour | Nested GraphType deriving (Show)
```

I can define an Parser for this structure (using [optparse-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative), imported as `OA`), recursively, as follows:

```hs
typeParser :: OA.Parser GraphType
typeParser =
  OA.flag' Colour (OA.long "colour")
    <|> OA.flag' Character (OA.long "character")
    <|> (OA.flag' Nested (OA.long "nested") <*> typeParser)
```

This lets me pass arguments such as

- `--colour` to get a value of `Colour`
- `--nested --colour` to get a value of `Nested Colour`
- `--nested --colour` to get a value of `Nested (Nested Colour)`
- and so on

Unfortunately, if I try to generate help text for ths parser, it fails.
This makes a degree of sense, because the "structure" of the parser is infinitely large.
However, I'm optimistic that there might be a some kind of work around for this, for instance transforming the inner `typeParser` so that we don't try to generate help text for it.

What's the smallest modification that can be made to this Parser to leave it with working help text?

---

In addition to not being able to generate help text, if I wanted to modify the parser to the following (to add a default, but also allow `--nested` by itself to parse as `Nested Character`), this will also hang, as opposed to reaching the default:

```hs
typeParser :: OA.Parser GraphType
typeParser =
  OA.flag' Colour (OA.long "colour")
    <|> OA.flag' Character (OA.long "character")
    <|> (OA.flag' Nested (OA.long "nested") <*> typeParser)
    <|> pure Character
```

---

I've already been able to work around the problem, by changing the Parser to the following

```hs
typeParser :: OA.Parser GraphType
typeParser = iter Nested <$> nestDepthParser <*> unnestedParser
  where
    iter f 0 v = v
    iter f n v = iter f (n - 1) (f v)
    nestDepthParser = OA.option OA.auto (OA.long "nest") <|> pure 0
    unnestedParser =
      OA.flag' Colour (OA.long "colour")
        <|> OA.flag' Character (OA.long "character")
        <|> pure Character
```

To specify a value of `Nested (Nested Colour)` in this parser, you'd pass `--nest 2 --colour`.
This works, but it's not ideal, as I really like the "multiple `--nesting` arguments" style of command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to modify the last parser in the question, to get the "multiple `--nesting`" style, using `many`, as follows:

```hs
typeParser :: OA.Parser GraphType
typeParser = iter Nested <$> nestDepthParser <*> unnestedParser
  where
    iter f 0 v = v
    iter f n v = iter f (n - 1) (f v)
    nestDepthParser = length <$> (many $ OA.flag' () (OA.long "nested"))
    unnestedParser =
      OA.flag' Colour (OA.long "colour")
        <|> OA.flag' Character (OA.long "character")
        <|> pure Character
```

`nestDepthParser` outputs a list (`[()]`) with a length equal to the number of `--nested` arguments, which can then be used to apply `Nested` the correct number of times.

This works (unlike the original code) because optparse-applicative has a specialized implementation of `many`, which doesn't hang.

Comment: I figured this out within 5 minutes of posting the question. With this said, other answers are welcome (and I won't self accept), as I don't think this code is as elegant as the "recursive applicative style" in the question, and am interested if there's another solution that's closer to that.